# Is it a good idea to load my array manually inside the program code rather than from file?

Tags: java, android

I want to know if there is an issue I don't know about with loading data into an array manually inside my code, rather than loading it from a file.

This:

```
classes.add(new CharClass("Rogue", "Dagger", "Cloak", "Light", R.drawable.rogue, 50, 75));
classes.add(new CharClass("Archer", "Bow", "Quiver", "Light", R.drawable.archer, 75, 50));
classes.add(new CharClass("Wizard", "Staff", "Spell", "Robe", R.drawable.wizard, 75, 75));
abilities.add(new Item("Cloak of Ghostly Concealment", "Ability", "Cloak", R.drawable.cloak_t6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0));
abilities.add(new Item("Cloak of Endless Twilight", "Ability", "Cloak", R.drawable.cloak_t5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0));
abilities.add(new Item("Cloak of the Red Agent", "Ability", "Cloak", R.drawable.cloak_t4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Versus:

A file like...

Rogue/Dagger/Cloak/Light//50/75

Archer/Bow/Quiver/Light//75/50

Wizard/Staff/Spell/Robe//75/75
...

And code like...

```
while(scanner.hasNext() {
    name = scanner.next;
    weapon = scanner.next;
    ability = scanner.next;
    armor = scanner.next;
    image = scanner.next;
    attack = scanner.next;
    dexterity = scanner.next;

    classes.add(new Item(name, weapon, ability, armor, image, attack, dexterity);
}
```

Comment: Data and code should be separate, and likely the data will change later or grow in size. Keep them separate.

Comment: Put in another way, by hard-coding data into the code itself, you add unnecessary inflexibility to your program.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend, given the examples here, to use file (try using JSON, as that works well). However, if it's something that 100% will not grow in size I suppose you could hard code it.